# Return approximation error with FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

I am solving a large system of equations. I would like to know to which extent the the solution that `FindRoot` returns to me is accurate:

```
sol = FindRoot[Equations, Start];
Norm[Equations /. sol]
```

The issue is that the second line the `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) operator takes a lot of time to execute. Since `FindRoot` compiles the function (over many variables), is there a way to utilize this speedup by letting `FindRoot` return the error.

e.g., I would like something like:

```
{sol, err} = FindRoot[Equations, Start, "ErrorReturn"]
```

Does this exist, or is there another efficient way to obtain the error?

Comment: I'm surprised the `ReplaceAll` takes ages to execute. How many equations are there?

Comment: There are 2500 Equations. However, it is strange that /. takes more time to execute than the findroot command, which evaluates the system many times

Comment: For the Fisrt case I would suggest you using `NMinimize` rather than `FindRoot`, But the definite answer lies behind your equations. Gimme an equation with error and a correct equation so I can write you the work around.

Comment: @Breugem Without specific example, I'm very suspicious about what you did. The replacement should not take that long and I'm not sure you don't have some other mistake. With the given information, it is hard to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ ] := 
       (Sow[Norm[#]]; #) &@{Sin[x + 1] + Sin[y - 3], x + y}
{result, err} = Reap[FindRoot[ f[x, y], {x, 0}, {y, 0}]];

{result, Min[err[[1]]]}
```

> {{x -> -0.429204, y -> 0.429204}, 1.11022*10^-16}

also useful:

```
 ListLogPlot[err[[1]]]
```

[image]

Of course instead of `Sow[Norm]` you could `Sow` the whole expression list in case you want to see which part is causing the largest error.

Answer (score 3):

In case your function is very slow, you can use a memoization trick like in the example below:

```
f[x_?NumberQ] := f[x] = (Pause[1/10];x^2 - 1);
```

Then the function you requested could be implemented as below:

```
MFindRoot[Equations_, Start_] := {FindRoot[Equations, Start, 
   StepMonitor :> (minsofar = Equations)], minsofar}
```

Comment: All great suggestions! Saves me a lot of time!